# Angular Service - Object Not Assignable to Array

Tags: angular, service

I'm attempting to grab a list of `locations` from my `API`. They are an array of `objects` with a `name` property only. This code below is actually retrieving them as they're showing in the web developer console, but for some reason, not assignable to my local variable and thus, not getting to my component via `*ngFor` with `'let loc of locations'` using `{{loc.name}}`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface Location {
  name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class LocationService {
  locations: Observable<Location[]>;
  private _locations: BehaviorSubject<Location[]>;
  private baseUrl: string;
  private dataStore: {
    locations: Location[];
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
    this.dataStore = { locations: <any>[] };
    this._locations = <BehaviorSubject<Location[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.locations = this._locations.asObservable();
  }

  loadAll() {
    this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/locations`).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        this.dataStore.locations = data;
        this._locations.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).locations);
      },
      (error) => console.log('Could not load Locations.')
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you would subscribe to `this.locations` and lets assume that `this.dataStore.locations` looks like `[1, 2, 3]` you will receive `{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}` because you assign array to object.

Second thing is that you looping through `locations` but it's a BehaviorSubject so you probably need to add `async` pipe to your html.

The solution could be:

```
loadAll() {
    this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/locations`).subscribe(
        (data) => {
            console.log(data);

            this.dataStore.locations = data;
            this._locations.next([...this.dataStore.locations]);
        },
        (error) => console.log('Could not load Locations.')
    );
}
```

and in html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  <div>{{item.someProperty}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much. I'm fairly new with Observables and this Object Assign is hard to manage. I've tried your code and it's still not working. I think the main issue is the cast of an object to type Array. Ultimately I'd like to have the locations be objects with a name property so I'm not really willing to change that. But when it comes back from the server, I need to get it into an array for the Observable, or at least this is what I'm thinking is true. But, with NGFOR, I should be able to iterate over an array of objects right? with obj.name syntax. I did try the Async pipe, it didnt' break the code but it also didn't work. my readout in web console from server is an array of two objects, each with a name property. Still so confused

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]0: {name: "Home"}1: {name: "Store"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
```